# Two ways to represent ex falso?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

According to [ProofWiki](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Rule_of_Explosion), the principle of explosion says that:

$$p \implies (\lnot p \implies q)$$

but sometimes it's also stated as

$$(p \land \lnot p) \implies q$$

Can one be converted to the other? How do you prove or show these?

If we know that $(p \implies q) \equiv \lnot p \lor q$ by definition, then substituting the 2nd representation:

$$((p \land \lnot p) \implies q) \equiv \lnot(p \land \lnot p) \lor q \equiv \lnot p \lor p \lor q$$

Is this just true due to law of excluded middle? Like either $p$ or $\lnot p$ is true, i.e. $p \lor \lnot p \equiv \text{T}$ before we even get to whatever $q$ is. Is that why we're able to say it?

Then the first representation is weird too:

$$(p \implies (\lnot p \implies q)) \equiv (\lnot p \lor (\lnot p \implies q)) \equiv (\lnot p \lor (p \lor q)) \equiv \lnot p \lor p \lor  q$$

I mean am I even on the right track here? How do you normally get these without "working backwards" and showing that they happen to be equivalent? Is there a more intuitive derivation of both of these?

Comment: Yes, the two are equivalent.

Comment: @amWhy Yes but I am asking something different than that

Comment: @user525966 Those are just two ways to write that a false premise implies any conclusion.

Comment: @user525966 I've proven that they are equivalent.

Comment: In terms of functional programming one of these is a “paired” representation and the other is “curried”. Both can be viewed as two argument functions that take a a proof of a proposition and its negation and yield a proof of a second proposition

Comment: @user525966 - The excluded middle has nothing to do with the proof of the equivalence of the two formulas, see my answer.

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco I admit I am sort of asking two questions at the same time. I know the excluded middle has nothing to do with the equivalence, but rather for that I am asking if that is why that implication is always true regardless of q, since TRUE or (anything) = TRUE

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco you say the equivalence has nothing to do with excluded middle (and i don’t think it does) but you use the non intuitionistically valid demorgan law in your proof.

Comment: @user525966 The “reason” behind the classical validity of a proposition can be difficult to untangle cause it all blends together. Intuitionistic logic is an example where excluded middle is not valid but explosion is. So inasmuch as intuitionistic logic is philosophically coherent for accepting one and not the other (there is another called “minimal logic” that rejects both), LEM cannot be the “reason” for explosion.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen - This is a good remark, but actually I can prove the equivalence of the two formulas in intuitionistic (even in minimal) logic, using natural deduction or sequent calculus. But this is out of the scope of the OP. Maybe it deserves another question. Anyway, I used De Morgan law just because it allows a short and simple proof.

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco Agree for the most part. My quibble wasn't with your proof/answer, just the claim that the proof shows that LEM isn't involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formulas $p \to (\lnot p \to q)$ and $(p \land \lnot p) \to q$ are equivalent because they are particular instances of a more general fact: the formulas $p \to (r \to q)$ and $(p \land r) \to q$ are equivalent. You can prove that checking that the two formulas actually have the same truth table. An alternative proof is the following:

\begin{align}
 p \to (r \to q)  &\iff  \lnot p \lor (\lnot r \lor q) &\text{by definition of } \to \\
&\iff (\lnot p \lor \lnot r) \lor q &\text{by associativity of } \lor  \\
&\iff \lnot(p \land r) \lor q &\text{by De Morgan law} \\
&\iff (p \land r) \to q &\text{by definition of }\to
\end{align}

Comment: @user525966 - Please, see my last edit.

Answer (score 1):

The two statements you post are logically equivalent.

$$\begin{align} p \to (\lnot p \to q) &\equiv \lnot p \lor (p \lor q) \tag{definion of $\to$}\\ \\
&\equiv (\lnot p \lor p) \lor q \tag{associativity of $\lor$}\\ \\
&\equiv \lnot (p \land \lnot p) \lor q \tag{DeMorgan's}\\ \\ 
&\equiv (p\land \lnot p)\to q\tag{definition of $\to$}\end{align}$$

You were heading in right direction, starting instead from $(p\land \lnot p)\to q$ and moving toward $p \to (\lnot p \to q)$. You just stopped too early.  Note each direction can be proven, because we have a string of equivalencies:  so to reverse the direction, just reverse the order of the steps.

$$\begin{align}
(p\land \lnot p)\to q &\equiv \lnot (p \land \lnot p)\lor q\tag{definition of $\to$}\\ \\  
&\equiv (\lnot p \lor  p) \lor q\tag{DeMorgan's}\\ \\ 
&\equiv \lnot p\lor (p \lor q)\tag{associativity of $\lor$}\\ \\ 
&\equiv p\to (\lnot p \to q)\tag{definition of $\to$}
\end{align}$$

---

First of all, we have $$p\to (q\to r) \vdash (p \land q) \to r\tag{importation}$$ and we have $$(p\land q) \to r \vdash p \to (q\to r)\tag{exportation}$$   Your question is a specific case of these, where $q = \lnot p$. [See this link for more information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_calculus#Basic_and_derived_argument_forms).

Comment: How / why are you using $\vdash$ here?

Comment: The turnstyle, $\vdash$ is the *syntactic entailment* operator.  $\phi \vdash \psi$, symbolises that $\psi$ is derivable from $\phi$ ( or "...can be proven from..." ) using the syntactic transformations of some logic system. @user525966

Answer (score 0):

To get pernickety, we need to distinguish the principle about *entailment* what is usually called Explosion, i.e.

> $(A \land \neg A) \vdash B$,

from the following principle that a *conditional* with a contradictory antecedent is always derivable:

> $\vdash (A \land \neg A) \to B$.

You can have logics with one principle and not the other.

Comment: What's the difference between $\vdash$ and $\to$? I know the former is more "is derivable from" but I always thought that was what implies was, really

Comment: @user525966 yes one is “derivable from” and is a metalogical relation (ie you use it to talk about the formal system) and the other is “implies” and is a logical connective (used within formal statements in the logic). They do oftentimes correspond exactly in the sense that we have $\vdash A\to B$ iff we have $A\vdash B$. One direction directly follows from the inference rule modus ponens if present. The other direction is called a *deduction theorem* and can be proved to apply to (for instance) one’s favorite deductive system for first order logic.

Comment: @user525966 not sure why I forgot to add this yesterday but in natural deduction systems where this holds, the two directions are unified as introduction and elimination rules for implication. Whereas, the “deduction theorem” direction being a nontrivial metatheorem, as described above, is typical in Hilbert-style systems.

Comment: What is metalogic, metatheory, exactly?

Comment: @user525966 (You have to @ me so I get pinged).  In logic, it is useful to distinguish between statements/proofs/theorems *in* formal systems and statements and results *about* formal systems (usually proven informally, using "ordinary mathematical reasoning", though we could formalize this too). The latter are called "meta_". "$\vdash A$" means "there is a formal proof of the statement $A$ in the deductive system under consideration"... that's a meta-statement *about* the system (and if true, $A$ is a (regular old) theorem of the system). See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metatheorem

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen So the very words we are using right now to talk about this, are we speaking metalogic right now?

Comment: @user525966 I suppose so (though we may also be speaking meta-meta-logic by talking about meta-logic).